# -bash: /usr/bin/nano: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, upgrade, nano

I have this problem on fresh install of Debian 8 (after doing `apt upgrade`).

`nano` is installed but when I try to use it to open a file :

`nano myfile.txt`

I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/nano: No such file or directory
```

I removed and reinstalled nano I get:

```
Setting up nano (2.7.4-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/nano to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /bin/nano to provide /usr/bin/pico (pico) in auto mode
```

And using `/usr/bin/editor myfile.txt` I can open the file.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/nano 
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/nano': No such file or directory`

Comment: What does `type nano` give you? Presumably Bash has hashed it under the wrong path. Have you tried logging on anew to see if this is limited to your shell instance?

Comment: Guys, for no obvious reason, `nano` command works now. As for `type nano` I get `nano is hashed (/bin/nano)`. Really strange! I never had such issue before.

Comment: @StephenKitt Could you explain what is cause of the problem , please.

Comment: @GAD3R `nano` used to include both `/bin/nano` and `/usr/bin/nano` (the latter as a symlink to the former). Going from Debian 8 to 9, `nano` [dropped the symlink](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767929); upgrading the package would then result in the error in the question, until a new shell is started or `hash -r` is run.

Answer (score 15):

In Debian 8, `nano` [includes both `/bin/nano` and `/usr/bin/nano`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/nano/filelist) (the latter is a symlink to the former). In Debian 9, [`/usr/bin/nano`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/nano/filelist) is no longer included (see [#767929](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767929) for details).

Presumably you upgraded from Debian 8 to a version of the package including the fix above. Your shell had remembered that `nano` was in `/usr/bin/nano`, but after the upgrade that was no longer the case. Running `hash -r` in your shell would fix that, as would starting a new shell.